# Connecting to Jersey REST Web Service from Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest, jersey

I created simple REST Web Service which takes three Strings from client and saves them to the database. It's working fine from Java client application.

Now, I want to do the same from Android device. What would be the best way to connect to service from my device and do the same?

I am new to Android, searched a lot on web, just couldn't find something simple enough to understand how to do it. Hope somebody can help.

RESTLocationService.java:

```
    @Path("/data")
public class RESTLocationService {

    @POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createDataInJSON(JSONObject data) throws JSONException {

    String lon = data.getString("lon");
    String lat = data.getString("lat");
    String dateTime = data.getString("dateTime");

    String location = "Longitude: " + lon + ", latitude: " + lat
            + ", time: " + dateTime + ".";

    DataHiber dataHiber = new DataHiber(lon, lat, dateTime);
    DBUtils.saveLocations(dataHiber);

    return Response.status(201).entity(location).build();
    }
}
```

RESTLocationClient.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("http://192.168.111.77:8080/TebLocationService/rest/data/post");

        String longy = "46.8888778877";
        String latty = "12.9485495894859";
        String timey = "29/03/2015 14:03";

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("lon", longy);
        obj.put("lat", latty);
        obj.put("dateTime", timey);

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, obj);

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: Extra jars will increase size of your application, You can easily call REST services using java HTTP URL Connection class

Comment: Extra jars, like, doing same like I did in Java app? Tried that, things got really complicated with them do I gave up on that I am searching for better solution.
Will try that with HTTP URL Connection, yes, just to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Android SDK does not have all classes which are available in JDK, hence you could not expect third party jar to work as is on android until unless the are not compatible, Hence I am suggesting to use standard classes available in Android SDK instead is using java application jars. HttPURLConnection is very comman class and thousands of example available on net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this, but most of the classes are deprecated. It's working fine (for now), will try to find better solution and post it here.

```
            Looper.prepare();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),
                    10000);
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

            String timey = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URL);
                obj.put("lon", longitude);
                obj.put("lat", latitude);
                obj.put("dateTime", timey);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);

                if (response != null) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            Looper.loop();
```